# Setting up Bind9 - lsb-base not in sources

Tags: dns, debian, lsb

I've been having real trouble installing Bind9 following this tutorial

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=39146

When I get to entering these commands:

```
apt-get -y build-dep lsb-base
apt-get source lsb-base -b
```

I constantly get the error "E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"
I am sure that I need to add a lsb-base source to my sources.list but I don't know what the link will be and the attributes.

I am running Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because your `apt` configuration seems to have lost all its *sources* (where it can retrieve packages from).

Usually, you should have something like this:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main
```

in your `/etc/apt/source.list` file (additionally you can use ``/etc/apt/source.list.d/*.list` files).

You really *must* have at least one source line, else you cannot install *any* packages.

If you want to install *source*-packages (as opposed to *binary*-packages, which are created from the former), you *also* need to add one (or several) `deb-src` lines:

```
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main
```

This is really unrelated to `lsb-base`

Comment: I have already done an apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. I do have 2 main source lines. However lsb-base doesn't seem to be part of a debian package!

Comment: no, [lsb-base](https://packages.debian.org/sid/lsb-base) (the binary-package) is built from [lsb](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/lsb) (the source package). anyhow, my answer was missing the info for installing "source" packages, which i have now added.